# alternating text position in latex

Tags: text-manipulation

I am writing my PhD thesis and I want to give the following format to my document (see image).

I appreciate any guidance provided.[image]

I have not found any help in the standard "text positioning settings"

Comment: Run `texdoc tufte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
I recommend the [`memoir`](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf#cite.REINGOLD07) class for this, here is a basic example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\footnotesinmargin
\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    Some text\footnote{a footnote in the margin.}.
    
    \blindtext
    \begin{marginfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
    \end{marginfigure}
    
    \blindtext
    
    \blindtext
    
    \blindtext
    
    \blindtext
    \footnote{notice that we are now on the other side of the page}
    
    \blindtext
    
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

There is much more that the `memoir` class can do but this should get you started.
The key points are `\footnotesinmargin` which, as the name suggests, puts all the footnotes in the margin, and the `marginfigure` (and analogous `margintable`) which puts figures (resp. tables) in the margin.

Comment: hm, `momoir` is excellent package, but for the  OP's situation the `tufte-book` document class can be more handy.